# Plotting multiple vector fields with different domains in a single graph

Tags: plotting, vector

I have attached a scheme of the problem. Essentially what I need is to plot 2 different vector fields in a single graph with different domains.

The underlying physical problem is to model electric current around and inside a sphere of a different material than the surroundings.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Show[
 StreamPlot[{1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#, #2}] < 1 &),   
                                BoundaryStyle -> Thick, StreamStyle -> {Thick, Green}],
 StreamPlot[{0, 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, StreamStyle -> {Thick, Red},
                               RegionFunction -> (Abs[#2] < 1.5 && Norm[{#, #2}] > 1 &),  
                               BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
  , PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled@.1]
```

> [image]

Comment: Apparently you found the question :P

Comment: @Öskå blind shot :p